# Windows HTTP server API, UrlPrefix failing with Error 5, on HttpAddUrl

Tags: windows, http, url, server

Good afternoon,

I'm following the example on Windows Http Server Api, found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364640(v=vs.85).aspx

I get my project to compile and work when I enter `http://localhost:8080/test` as the URl into HttpAddUrl function, and point my browser to `http://localhost:8080/test` on the same machine as I run the http server in the above example.

The webpage shows the response and everything works well.

here is my call to HttpAddUrl

```
        retCode = HttpAddUrl(
        hReqQueue,    // Req Queue
        L"http://localhost:8080/test/",      // Fully qualified URL
        NULL          // Reserved
        );
```

My problem, however is sending the request from another machine on the same LAN.

I tried pointing the browser to `http://192.168.1.2:8080/test/`  but I got a 404 error,

Then I tried changing the HttpAddUrl function to

```
        retCode = HttpAddUrl(
        hReqQueue,    // Req Queue
        L"http://192.168.1.2:8080/test/",      // Fully qualified URL
        NULL          // Reserved
        )
```

This only returned retCode = 5  (which I also cannot determine the meaning of, if somebody can help me determine the enumeration for this error variable)

Does anybody know what I am supposed to enter into the HttpAddUrl function if I want to sen an HTTP request from another machine to the local server.

Thanks,
-D

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, it turns out I was not running Visual Studio with Admin privileges, error 5 was system error "Access Denied"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

The URL of `L"http://192.168.1.2:8080/test/"` was corrent

Comment: I ran into this too. A worrying thing about it is that admin is needed to do this on a port number above 1024 at all!